Issue with integrating GS1 API to Android application
I have a barcode scanner application in Android Kotlin but how can I integrate GS1 API into it so that when scanning any barcode then it will show the details about the barcode item from GS1 server. Also is there any API of GS1 available for free?
I tried using free RFID API but it didn't work for me.
